# _name (underscore prefix) vs name what's the difference of the option name for firewall configuration in OpenWRT?

Tags: firewall, openwrt

I saw different writing of name option for OpenWRT firewall configuration, seems all work fine. What's the meaning of the different formats?

[_name](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/cifs.server)

```
option '_name' 'Don'\''t track NETBIOS Service'
```

[name](http://wiki.openwrt.org/inbox/openswanxl2tpvpn)

```
option 'name' 'vpn'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both if them do nothing, they’re purely for your convenience. The `name` option is also made a comment on the actual IPTables rule, like this:

`-A zone_wan_input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -m comment --comment Allow-DHCP-Renew -j ACCEPT`

Here’s the [official documentation](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/firewall#rules) for firewall rules.

Comment: Seems no mention to _name

Comment: Of course. It doesn’t do anything, why would it be documented?

Comment: You linked the document, so I thought I missed something.